# Set an Entry inside a Grid row cell in .cs Xamarin Form

Tags: grid

I need to add dynamically row to my grid (ok), but the first cell need to be numeric, the second one text and so on.

But, I didn't find any example for this, it's always in the .xalm :/

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Maxime, The `Grid` control is best used for static content where you know the amount of rows / columns you need. What you are describing could be better achieved using a `StackLayout` and perhaps an `ItemTemplate` and `TemplateSelector`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer !

I manage to do what I wanted using Grid.SetRow and Grid.SetColumn.

But, if it's becoming too complex, I will test using stacklayout !